# Debugging vanishing share box on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, debugging

I have a few Facebook groups and pages and they all work fine with sharing whatever I want. But on my main page (last 24 hrs), whenever I try to share something, all that happens is the share box pops up for a millisecond (no text) and simply vanishes.

I’ve tried it in both Chrome and Firefox, and on different computers, cleared caches, the lot; same result. It’s a fully public page too, so it’s not a security issue, I would think.

At the moment, the only way I’m able to get a rough idea what’s going on, is using Chrome’s right click → inspect element, or Firefox’es similar function. I’m not sure what I am looking for though, and I presume there is better software to debug things like this.

What software or plugins do you need to see what the code is actually doing as it executes? And hopefully highlight hangup points or show me where the issue likely is.

Comment: It's really difficult to follow code in this way, especially with deployed code such as Facebook. Chrome Inspector contains more than enough tools to debug any Javascript but normally you will need access to the live code to  debug properly.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an issue with Facebook products and not an issue with platform, the best way to highlight this issue is to file a bug report using Facebook's Report form (https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/). It is highly likely that this is a known issue that engineers are working on, but it doesn't hurt to report the bug.